# Docker entrypoint will not prompt for my input

Tags: bash, ssh, docker

Here's the entrypoint of my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ssh-agent bash\
           && ssh-add directory/id_rsa
```

If I run my docker container with `docker run my_conatiner -rm`, I get:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

instead of being prompted to insert the private key password.

If I run, however, with `ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash`, and paste the two commands manually, I get prompted to insert the password for the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ssh-agent bash` will start a new `bash` with the environment variables set. But since you don't provide any input, the `bash` exits, together with the `ssh-agent` and then in the original `bash`, there is again no connection to your `ssh-agent`. With a diagram of processes how they are called:

```
bash
 '- ssh-agent bash
   '- bash < no input, exits cleanly
 '- ssh-add ...
```

What you want to do instead is to invoke `ssh-agent` the [intended way](https://superuser.com/questions/1185247/installing-ssh-private-key-on-freenas-for-outgoing-ssh-rsync/1185251#1185251):

```
ENTRYPOINT eval `ssh-agent` \
       && ssh-add directory/id_rsa
```